# Validate serial reading

Tags: python, serial-port

I'm currently trying to read a serialport and the data is sometimes "corrupted".

I am expecting data like this

`['CPS', '0', 'CPM', '11', 'uSv/hr', '0.06', 'SLOW']`

The first reading after opening the serial port is always

`['\x00']`

then reading data is fine for a unknown time, until the serialport delivers somethin like this

`['CPS', '0', 'CPM', '21', 'uSv/hr', '\x000.11', 'SLOW']`

I already tried to make sure the reading is correct by 
this, rather ugly, condition checking:

```
serialData = serialConnection.readline()
serialData = "".join(serialData.split())
serialList = serialData.split(",")
if (len(serialList) < 7 or serialList[5][0] == "\\"
    or serialList[0] != "CPS" or serialList[2] != "CPM"):
    uSvH = 0.1
else:
    uSvH = float(serialList[5])
```

So I'm checking whether the read data is the correct size(seven entrys), the first entry always has to be CPS and when a \x* is recieved instead of a float it sets the reading to a default value.

But somehow this fails when a corrupt reading occurs.

Is there a better way to sanitize the reading or make sure the data that is received is fine?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was thinking too complicated. A simple try except statement finished the job.

```
 if(len(serialList) == 7):
    try:
        uSvH = float(serialList[5])
    except ValueError:
        uSvH = 0.1
if (len(serialList) < 7 or serialList[0] != "CPS" or serialList[2] != "CPM"):
    uSvH = 0.1
```

Now the script passes some random readings.